# How can I get the Source Code of a specific URL in a Visual Basic Application?

Tags: vb.net

The current method that I'm trying to use to achieve this is:

```
    Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    Dim url As String = txtUrl.Text
    output.Items.Add(url)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
    output.Items.Add(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)

End Sub
End Class
```

I was pretty confident this would work but my App is proving otherwise... Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I used a different method:

```
    Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    Dim Client As New WebClient()
    Dim url As String = txtUrl.Text

    Dim html As String = Client.DownloadString(New Uri(url))
    output.Text = html

End Sub
```

End Class

This worked perfectly. output is RichTextBox if you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHTML`

Comment: I got this error 'System.NullReferenceException' and it crashed

Comment: is there an import that I'm missing or anything? i'm currently using 'Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net'

Comment: Is this VBA, VB6, or VB.net?

Comment: It is VB.net. I was mistaken

Comment: @EddieFoster : What you were missing was that you never let the page load before you tried to get its contents. The web browser must download the page before you can access it, but your code is run almost instantly after you tell it to navigate. This is a common mistake that I see often on Stack Overflow, and it can be solved by subscribing to and putting the code in the web browser's [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).